# How can I make the background transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, illustration

Are there any easy way to make the white background transparent?

[image]

Comment: Hello! Did any of the answers work for you? Please follow up- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select "Magic Wand Tool" from tools and click the area you want to remove white space. Then hit delete. But you should double click to remove lock icon on background color if you have only one layer. Then you can save it as PNG.

Comment: Although this is one of the first lessons for an amateur Photoshop user, it is considered a "destructive" procedure and, therefore, is not a best practice. Any method that deletes pixels from the work makes it difficult to adjust later. If you do use this method, make sure to perform this on a copy of the layer or a copy of the original file.

Answer (score 1):

HOW to make a transparent background for this or any image depends on how you intend to use the "cut-out" version. If you simply want to remove the background, the least-destructive and adjustable way is to use a [mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html).

[image]

[image]

Assuming you want to keep the "white" color in the subject of the image, most normal removal methods, like using "multiply" or the magic wand, will remove most of the white inside and outside of your character. Using a mask, you just "paint" the area you want to hide. In the case of your image, this is relatively simple and doesn't take much time while still being adjusted to your preference. Here is a quick PNG with the background masked:

[image: Here is a PNG with a transparent background.]

Now, if you mean to overlay this character onto another background, what I normally do is use a combination of a mask and a "multiply" blending mode in order to make the edge softer and hide any white "halo" around the subject. To do this, I would take the same mask I drew for the character, move that to a white background layer and then change the subject layer blending mode to "multiply". I would then just "cut-in" the mask as necessary to blend the outline of the subject more with whatever background these two layers are on top of.

Comment: @user51918 Great! Don't forget to mark an answer as "correct" with a green check mark if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Blending to Multiply and play with Opacity.
If multiply doesn't help try other Blending modes (e.s. Darken)

[image: Blending layer]

Comment: Please note that using the "Multiply" blending mode alone for the layer shown in the OP will make all white in the image to not show, including the white that makes up the subject.